# Return multiple COLUMN_JSON results as JSON array

Tags: mariadb

I am storing data in standard tables in a MariaDB, but would like to return records from related tables as a JSON string.

What I intend to do is have a function where I can pass in `exerciseId` and the function returns a JSON string of all related `exerciseMuscle` records, meaning each `exercise` record returned by a stored proc can also include nested data from child tables.

I have been able to create JSON records using `COLUMN_JSON` and `COLUMN_CREATE` but can only get this to return as a set of individual records, rather than an array of JSON values as a need. The SQL I'm using is:

```
select
    e.id, 
    CONVERT(COLUMN_JSON(COLUMN_CREATE(
        'role', em.muscleRoleName, 
        'muscle', em.muscleName
    )) USING utf8) as musclesJson
from
    exercise e
    inner join exerciseMuscle em
            on e.id = em.exerciseId
where
    e.id = 96;
```

This returns:

```
| id | musclesJson 
| 96 | {"role":"main","muscle":"biceps"}
| 96 | {"role":"secondary","muscle":"shoulders"}
```

When what I want is:

```
| id | musclesJson 
| 96 | [{"role":"main","muscle":"biceps"},{"role":"secondary","muscle":"shoulders"}]
```

Is it possible to return multiple results in one row without having to iterate through the results and build it manually? If I add a `group by` to the SQL then the JSON only includes the first record.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: MariaDB 10.0.24, just changed tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out it was `GROUP_CONCAT` that I needed, and specifying a comma as the delimiter. So changing my SQL to:

```
select
    e.id, 
    CONVERT(
        GROUP_CONCAT(
            COLUMN_JSON(
                COLUMN_CREATE(
                    'role', em.muscleRoleName, 
                    'muscle', em.muscleName
                )
            )
            SEPARATOR ','
        ) USING utf8) as muscles 
from
    exercise e
    inner join exerciseMuscle em
            on e.id = em.exerciseId
where
    e.id = 96;
```

Returns:

```
| id | musclesJson 
| 96 | {"role":"main","muscle":"biceps"},{"role":"secondary","muscle":"shoulders"}
```